# seletc date query using prepared statement

Tags: mysql, date

In the database same date is multiple time there. The table data contain date with time if I use this it is not giving the record that I need to modify. I want `2012-11-21` this date all records. But `token_gen_time` it contains `2012-11-21 1:00:00`. How can I write query to select depending on date.

```
SELECT * FROM mias_log
where activity_status='Token Generated' 
AND token_gen_time='2012-11-21 '
```

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the time from your `token_gen_time` using the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to return values matching only the date

```
SELECT * 
FROM mias_log 
where activity_status='Token Generated' 
  AND Date(token_gen_time) = '2012-11-21'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the date part with [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

```
SELECT * 
FROM mias_log 
where activity_status = 'Token Generated' 
and date(token_gen_time) = '2012-11-21'
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make use of index (if available in token_gen_time), use this

```
SELECT * 
FROM mias_log 
where activity_status = 'Token Generated' 
and token_gen_time >= '2012-11-21' 
and token_gen_time < '2012-11-22'
```